# Is it natural to say "speak with one's voice raised" meaning to speak angrily and loudly?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it natural to say *speak with one's voice raised* meaning to speak angrily and loudly? For example:

> Kate and Mike were talking **with their voices raised**. I think they had an argument.

Comment: If I'm standing in front of a crowd of people without a microphone, I have to raise my voice to be heard by everyone. It does not mean that I'm angry, merely that I speaking loudly.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of the phrase "raise one's voice". From you comment I can't get whether mine is valid or not

Comment: If they spoke with their voices raised, it means they spoke loudly. That they spoke *angrily* can only be inferred from the second sentence—and, even then, it might not be true. People can have arguments without being angry. People can also be angry without *speaking* angrily. (It's also possible to speak angrily in a quiet voice.)

Comment: I would go with *"Kate and Mike were talking with raised voices. I think they had an argument."* If there is nothing in the related words to suggest a noisy environment then the *"raised voices"* wording suggests disagreement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual expression is "... with raised voices".  This would usually imply an argument of some kind, since that is the usual reason for shouting. Without additional context (such as "... to be heard in the noisy party") I'd assume that Kate and Mike were arguing noisily.